# Generating vectors fixing some values in Julia

Tags: julia

I need vectors such that

```
[1,1,1,1,...,1]
[2,1,1,1,...,1]
[3,1,1,1,...,1]
.
.
.
[J1,1,1,1,...,1]
[1,2,1,1,...,1]
.
.
.
[1,J2,1,1,...,1]
[1,1,2,1,...,1]
.
.
.
[1,1,J3,1,...,1]
.
.
.
[1,1,1,1,1,JD]
```

In the case of `D=5`, it is easy to implement.

```
J = [3,4,5,3,4]
D = length(J)
H = Vector{Vector{Int8}}(undef,1+sum( J.-1 ))
cum = cumsum(J)
H[1:cum[1]] = [[i,1,1,1,1] for i=1:J[1]]
H[cum[1]+1:cum[2]-1] = [[1,j,1,1,1] for j=2:J[2]]
H[cum[2]+0:cum[3]-2] = [[1,1,k,1,1] for k=2:J[3]]
H[cum[3]-1:cum[4]-3] = [[1,1,1,l,1] for l=2:J[4]]
H[cum[4]-2:cum[5]-4] = [[1,1,1,1,m] for m=2:J[5]];

#15-element Vector{Vector{Int8}}:
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# [3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
# [1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
# [1, 4, 1, 1, 1]
# [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
# [1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
# [1, 1, 4, 1, 1]
# [1, 1, 5, 1, 1]
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
# [1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
```

How can I implement it with general `D`?
I wrote the code as follows:

```
J = [3,5,4,2,5,8]
D = length(J)
H = Vector{Vector{Int8}}(undef,1+sum( J.-1 ))
cum = cumsum(J)
for d = 1:D
    if d==1
        for q = 1:J[1]
            one_hot = ones(Int8,D)
            one_hot[d] = q
            H[q] = one_hot
        end
    else
        for q = 2:J[d]
            one_hot = ones(Int8,D)
            one_hot[d] = q
            H[cum[d-1]+(2-d)+q-1] = one_hot
        end
    end
end
```

But I think there is a better method.
Do you have any idea?

**EDIT**

Thank you for providing ideas.
I conducted a numerical experiment to compare your code. Apparently, AboAmmar's code is the best in terms of efficiency.

```
using BenchmarkTools
J = [120,120,120,120,120]
@btime get_H_August(J)
  16.900 μs (600 allocations: 79.59 KiB)
@btime get_H_Stepan(J)
  1.733 μs (2 allocations: 23.39 KiB)
@btime get_H_AboAmmar(J)
  705.755 ns (1 allocation: 3.06 KiB)
@btime get_H_Dan(J)
  72.900 μs (1795 allocations: 177.88 KiB)

function get_H_August(J)
    H = typeof(J)[ones(size(J))] # first row of 1's
    sizehint!(H, 1+sum(J.-1))    # we know the final size
    for (idx, j) in enumerate(J)
        for i = 2:j
            # Place `i` at index `idx` and 1's elsewhere
            row = ifelse.(1:length(J) .== idx, i, 1)
            push!(H, row)
        end
    end
    return H
end

function get_H_Stepan(J)
    colsize = sum(J) - (length(J) - 1)
    M = fill(1, (colsize, length(J)))
    for (j, jval) in enumerate(J)
        if j == 1
            M[1:J[1], 1] .= 1:J[1]
            continue
        end
        s = sum(@view J[1:j-1]) - j + 3  # start index is
        # sum of previous J's - number of intersections + 1
        # number of intersections = length of previous J's array - 1
        # length of previous J's array is j - 1
        # so, sum - (j - 1 - 1) + 1
        f = s + (jval - 2)               # final index
        M[s:f, j] .= 2:jval              # filling
    end  
    return M
end

function get_H_AboAmmar(J)
    l = 1
    H = ones(Int8, sum(J)-length(J)+1,length(J)) 
    for (i,j) in pairs(J)
        for k in 2:j
            H[l+=1,i] = k
        end 
    end
    return H
end

function get_H_Dan(J)
    D = length(J)
    H = vcat([[vcat(ones(Int8,i-1),Int8(k),ones(Int8,D-i)) 
                for k=1+(i>1):J[i]] for i=1:D]...)
    return H
end
```

Comment: This probably isn't more efficient. But it is succinter: `vcat([ones(Int,length(J))], [[((j,v) -> ( t = ones(Int,length(J)); t[j]=v; return t))(i, j) for j=2:J[i]] for i=1:length(J)]...)` and only J is needed as input.

Comment: Another method (somewhat useful for confusing readers) is `collect(eachrow(reverse(sortslices(vcat(zeros(Int,1,5),[(zeros(Int,5,5)+i*I)[reverse(J).>i,:] for i=1:D]...).+1;dims=1),dims=2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be written quite easily in array comprehension:

```
julia> J = [3, 4, 5, 3, 4];

julia> l = length(J);

julia> H = [(v=ones(Int8,l);v[i]=k;v) for (i,j) in pairs(J) for k in 2:j];

julia> H = [[ones(Int8,l)]; H]
15-element Vector{Vector{Int8}}:
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 4, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 4, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 5, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
```

If you want something 10X faster, then build `H` as a matrix and use its rows like this:

```
l = 1
H = ones(Int8, sum(J)-length(J)+1,length(J)) 
for (i,j) in pairs(J)
    for k in 2:j
        H[l+=1,i] = k
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come with

```
J = [3, 4, 5, 3, 4]
colsize = sum(J) - (length(J) - 1)
M = fill(1, (colsize, length(J)))

for (j, jval) in enumerate(J)
    if j == 1
        M[1:J[1], 1] .= 1:J[1]
        continue
    end

    s = sum(@view J[1:j-1]) - j + 3  # start index is
    # sum of previous J's - number of intersections + 1
    # number of intersections = length of previous J's array - 1
    # length of previous J's array is j - 1
    # so, sum - (j - 1 - 1) + 1

    f = s + (jval - 2)               # final index
    M[s:f, j] .= 2:jval              # filling
end

# Your vectors
@show M[1, :]
@show M[2, :]
@show M[3, :]
@show M[4, :]
@show M[5, :]

# For debug
# for row in eachrow(M)
#     println(row)
# end
```

My idea is to look at the desired vectors as rows of a matrix and to fill the matrix' *columns*.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to do this of course - I think this is readable and concise enough.

```
J = [3,4,5,3,4]

H = typeof(J)[ones(size(J))] # first row of 1's
sizehint!(H, 1+sum(J.-1))    # we know the final size
for (idx, j) in enumerate(J)
    for i = 2:j
        # Place `i` at index `idx` and 1's elsewhere
        row = ifelse.(1:length(J) .== idx, i, 1)
        push!(H, row)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This version looks quite short and cute:

```
julia> J = [3,4,5,3,4];

julia> D = length(J);

julia> H = vcat([[vcat(ones(Int8,i-1),Int8(k),ones(Int8,D-i)) 
                for k=1+(i>1):J[i]] for i=1:D]...)
15-element Vector{Vector{Int8}}:
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 4, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 3, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 4, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 5, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
```